# bug in emmeans confidence intervals when type="response"?

Tags: confidence-interval, emmeans

It seems that calling `confint()` on an emmeans object gives spurious results when `type="response"`.

### Example:

- *without* type="response" :

```
Condition = A:
 contrast           estimate    SE    df  z.ratio p.value
 Y - X              0.496       0.296 Inf 1.676   0.0937
```

The confidence intervals provided by `confint()` agree, in that they cross zero:

```
Condition = A:
 contrast           estimate    SE    df    asymp.LCL   asymp.UCL
 Y - X              0.496       0.296 Inf    -0.084     1.076
```

But now look what happens when emmeans has been asked for `type="response"`.

I should note this is coming from a glmer model with family="binomial", so the estimates are odds ratios or, in this case, back-transformed from the logit:

- *with* type="response":

```
Condition = A:
 contrast           odds.ratio    SE       df  z.ratio p.value
 Y / X              1.64          0.486    Inf 1.676   0.0937
```

So you see here, the z-ratio and p-values are the same, as should be the case. But look what happens when you call `confint()`:

```
Condition = A:
 contrast           odds.ratio    SE      df.     asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Y / X              1.64          0.486   Inf     0.919      2.93
```

Suddenly the confidence intervals do *not* cross zero, even though previously the p-value was = 0.0937 and the non-back-transformed CI *does* cross zero.

What's going on here, is this a bug???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An odds ratio is always a positive number. Moreover, it is a ratio, not a difference. When two quantities have a ratio of 1, they are the same. Note that the interval has a lower end less than 1 and an upper limit greater than 1; that is consistent with the test results you have.

Finally, note that you can obtain this interval directly from the interval for the difference of logits: exp{-0.084}=0.919 and exp{1.076}=2.93.

Comment: Ah of course--I did know that, and now I feel dumb. Essentially, crossing 1 instead of 0 is the indication that the effect is not significant at alpha = 0.05... thank you!!!

Comment: Believe me, I am familiar with feeling dumb... But we have it straightened out and I bet there are others who have the same confusion.